# Possible to make custom class named "Map", and still reference the Haxe "Map" class?

Tags: haxe

Is it possible to make a class called Map:

```
// src/test/Map.hx
package test;
class Map {
    public function new ( a : Int, b : Int : c : Int ) {
        trace( a + b + c );
    }
}
```

And then somehow access both this new `Map` class AND the [original Haxe Map construct](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html) in Foo.hx?

```
// src/test/Foo.hx
package test;
class Foo {
    var map1 : test.Map         = new test.Map( 1, 2, 3 );
    var map2 : Map<Int, String> = [ 0 => "Hello" ];
}
```

This doesn't work, because the `map2` type is automatically resolving to `test.Map` (not the Haxe one) because Foo.hx is part of the `test` package which contains the new `Map` class.

If the Haxe `Map` construct was part of a package, this would be easy (could just say `package_name.Map`). However, it has no package. So is there no way to access both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Haxe 4 you will be able to use `haxe.ds.Map`.

Meanwhile, you should be able to access haxe's `Map` with `std.Map`.

Comment: I think one more solution is `import Map as StdMap`